# monacaで使用するnend広告、リリースビルドで表示されるが、クリックしても開きません

Tags: javascript, monaca, jquery, html5, nend

monacaで使用するnend広告について質問です。
複数広告枠を持っていて広告コードをタグの中に入れてます。
１つの広告コードを複数コピーするわけではなく
複数枠の広告を１つずつ貼っています。
広告の状態はアクティブです。

３つの質問です。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

『リリースビルドで広告は表示されますが、いざクリックをすると広告は開きません』
解決策を教えていただけないしょうか？

『表示される箇所とされない箇所があるのはなぜか？』
できればその解決策を教えてください。

『１つのhtmlファイルにnend広告数の制限はないのでしょうか？』

nend広告の広告コードをそのままbodyタグの中に貼り付けています。
index.htmlは２つとも広告が表示されますが、ex01.htmlでは、下方の広告しか表示されません。

index.html↓

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nend_params = {"media":42561,"site":230558,"spot":659077,"type":1,"oriented":3};</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script>
<h2><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="ex01.html">コチラ</a></p></h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
var nend_params = {"media":42561,"site":230558,"spot":660921,"type":1,"oriented":3};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script>
```

ex01.html↓

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nend_params = {"media":42561,"site":230558,"spot":660917,"type":1,"oriented":3};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a href="index.html">戻る</a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var nend_params = {"media":42561,"site":230558,"spot":660919,"type":1,"oriented":3};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js1.nend.net/js/nendAdLoader.js"></script>
```

表示されているindex.htmlの中身をex01.htmlに入れ広告枠だけ変更してみましたが変わりませんでした。
head内には以下を入れています。

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<script src="js/ncmb-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

コンポネートは
JQuery Mobile(Monaca Version),JQuery (Monaca Version),を追加しています。

プラグインは
Custom Config,InAppBrowser,MonacaPlugin,Nifty,Nofitication,Splashscreen,Whitelistです。

追記---------------------------

さきほどリリースビルドを行いました。
広告をクリックすると、ほぼ開きません。
なぜかはわかりませんが、たまに開く程度です（DMM.18のみ）
ヘッド内に以下のスクリプトを書いています
どのようにすれば直るのか、助けてください。

```
<script>
   var nend_params;
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var nend_links = document.querySelectorAll('.nend_wrapper a');
    for(var i = 0; i < nend_links.length; i+=1){
    (function() {
        var href = nend_links[i].href;
        nend_links[i].href = "#";
        nend_links[i].onclick = function(){window.open(href, '_system'); return false;}
      })();
    }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: まず広告を一つのみ掲載したときに正常に動作するか確認することが先だと思います。

Comment: 一つのみ掲載した時には正常に動きました。閲覧端末の言語設定は日本語です。

Comment: 広告の複数掲載についてはnendに確認した方が確実と思います。デバッグは[GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/)を使用して確認すれば問題点を把握することができます。

Comment: 本文を追記しましたので、できれば助けてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

掲載したコードがすべてなら、JavaScriptのコードは`for`ループを回ることなく終了します。
となると、本当にデバッグしましたか？という話になります。

```
var nend_links = document.querySelectorAll('.nend_wrapper a');
```

クラス名`nend_wrapper`は、JavaScriptのコードにしか存在しません。
下記のように、`DIV`タグにクラス名を付けてnendの広告コードを埋め込めば、`for`ループの処理を実行します。

```
<div class="nend_wrapper">
    ....
</div>
```

掲載したコードがすべてなら、問題は「正常な動き」を把握しているか？ということです。

> 広告をクリックすると、ほぼ開きません。
>   なぜかはわかりませんが、たまに開く程度です（DMM.18のみ）

「開く」と記載されていますが、このJavaScriptのコードは、通常のブラウザで広告を表示させるための処理です。
広告が表示されたとしても、それは`window.open()`によって表示したわけではありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。<div>だったのですね！もう少し勉強しておきます。今回はありがとうございました。